# Missing link to lisp sources in describe-function / describe-variable

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am used to that the help buffer of describe-function, describe-variable & co contain a link to the lisp sources where the symbol is defined. I get a link for symbols defined in my own libraries. I have the C source of Emacs installed, and for symbols defined there I also get a link. However the link is gone for symbols defined within standard lisp libraries that come with Emacs. I have Ubuntu, and I have the emacs23-el package installed.

Comment: I have Emacs 24, and installing the emacs24-el package just now made the lisp source links appear for me.  Are you sure you're running Emacs 23?

Comment: Try to provide a reproducible recipe, starting from `emacs -Q`. Yes, in some situations Emacs cannot tell where a given function was last defined.  It's possible that you stumbled on an Emacs bug. But it's also possible that the behavior is expected and Emacs has no way of knowing more about the source definition.

Comment: It's been 6 months, and no update.  Do you see the problem when you start without your init file (`emacs -Q`)? If not, bisect your init file recursively until you find the culprit code. And consider closing the question if it is no longer relevant.

Comment: Maybe they were autoloaded, but not yet fully loaded? Autoloaded symbols don't provide their location. Also it is possible to dynamically define symbols, which then will not have their location info.